# ESLint configuration with react-scripts not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, react-scripts, git-husky

I want to configure eslint as a precommit hook and my project is made using create-react-app. I have the following configuration with me currently. But with the following Lint staged is not running before commits. Also, I cannot install any other version of ESLint as react-scripts requires eslint with version 5.6.0 and it throws an error if I try to manually install some other version of it. What could be the issue here?

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-env": "^2.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-css-modules": "^2.0.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui": "0.20.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-appinsights": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-drag-listview": "^0.1.4",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^2.3.0",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^8.0.1",
    "react-picky": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js start",
    "dev": "./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js start",
    "sbx": "./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js start",
    "stage": "./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js start",
    "prod": "./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js start",
    "build": "./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "lint": "react-scripts run lint"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "airbnb",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
      ],
      "indent": 2,
      "no-console": "error",
      "no-var": "error",
      "import/prefer-default-export": "off"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.test.js",
          "**/*.test.jsx"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "echo aayushi && lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "lint"
    ],
    "*.{json,md,html}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-duplicate-keys": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-function-name": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-instanceof": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-literals": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-new-target": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-super": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "applicationinsights": "^1.0.8",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-transform-css": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-saml": "^1.0.0",
    "powerbi-report-component": "^1.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.3",
    "workerize-loader": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./src/test-setup.js",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "babel-jest",
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg)$": "jest-transform-css"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-project|react-native-button)/)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "my-module.js": "<rootDir>/path/to/my-module.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss|svg)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ]
  }
}
```